# Mapping through multiple array object

Tags: javascript

I am mapping through two different array objects and comparing them using their id's

```
  const Users =[{"id":"1","name":"Ben"},{"id":"2","name":"Khloe"},{"id":"3","name":"Ayra"}];
  const Connects = [{userId: "1", status:"pending", type: 'skipped'}, {userId: "3", status:"pending", type: 'invited'}];
  
  const connectMap = Connects.reduce((map, { userId, type, status }) => {
    let connect = map.get(userId) || []
    connect.push(type, status)
    return map.set(userId, connect)
  }, new Map())
  
  const array = Users.map(({ id, name }) => ({
    name,
    type: (connectMap.get(id) || []).join(', '),
    status: (connectMap.get(id) || []).join(', '),
  }))
  
  console.info(array)
```

I am getting this as an output

```
[
  { name: 'Ben', type: 'skipped, pending', status: 'skipped, pending' },
  { name: 'Khloe', type: '', status: '' },
  { name: 'Ayra', type: 'invited, pending', status: 'invited, pending'
  }
]
```

So you'll notice the `type` & `status` keys are having two values separated with a comma, which is not what I want.

I want an output like this

```
[
      { name: 'Ben', type: 'skipped', status: 'pending' },
      { name: 'Khloe', type: '', status: '' },
      { name: 'Ayra', type: 'invited', status: 'pending'
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate out the status and type values inside `connectMap` - right now you just have one array for each, so of course

```
type: (connectMap.get(id) || []).join(', '),
status: (connectMap.get(id) || []).join(', '),
```

will return the same thing.

But because the input and output arrays look to all be one-to-one, it'd make more sense to `.map`. First turn the `Connects` into an object indexed by `userId`, then map the Users and look up the ID on that object for each user.

```js
const Users =[{"id":"1","name":"Ben"},{"id":"2","name":"Khloe"},{"id":"3","name":"Ayra"}];
const Connects = [{userId: "1", status:"pending", type: 'skipped'}, {userId: "3", status:"pending", type: 'invited'}];

const connectsById = Object.fromEntries(
  Connects.map(({ userId, status, type }) => [userId, { type, status }])
);
const output = Users.map(({ id, name }) => ({
  name,
  ...(connectsById[id] || { status: '', type: '' })
}));
console.log(output);
```